# How to install usb adapter wifi driver on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: wireless, adapter

How to install usb adapter wifi driver (D-link Dwa 171) on Ubuntu 23.04?

Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLOmv.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; mokutil --sb`

Comment: I edit , and i put a image for you can see it

Comment: See https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu-20210916 as I would install Ubuntu first and then use another means to connect to internet such as USB tethering to a smartphone

Comment: see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/1698042) it is the right way to add any wifi driver.

Comment: @TalaatEtman That answer is for wifi device manufactured by Broadcom, this device is made by Realtek

Answer (score 2):

In terminal

```
cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
sudo wget https://gitlab.com/jeremy53561/wireless-info-1/-/raw/master/8821cu.ko
sudo depmod -a
```

reboot
Then in terminal

```
sudo apt install git dkms
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu-20210916.git
cd 8821cu-20210916
chmod +x install-driver.sh
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

And you should be set

Comment: then what i do after that?

Comment: I fixed my problem thanks!

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: By your solution Thanks

Comment: Click the check mark next to it to accept it as the answer, you are welcome

Comment: @Jeremy31 can you please help me with this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484424/slow-5ghz-download-speed-with-tp-link-t3u-plus-on-ubuntu-23-04

Comment: This solved installing the 0bda:c811 under Ubuntu 23.10 as well. Perfect, thank you!