# Slow 5Ghz download speed with TP-LINK T3U Plus on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi, 23.04

I have a TP-LINK T3U Plus AC1300 USB Adapter. On Windows, it gave me around 180 Mbps download and 170 Mbps upload on 5Ghz.

But on Ubuntu 23.04, the download speed on 5Ghz is only 12-16 Mbps, though the upload speed remains high at 160-170 Mbps. On 2.4Ghz, I get 20-35 Mbps download and 70 Mbps upload.

My internet plan is 200Mbps, so I expect to get close to this speed.

I believe this might be a driver issue. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Update 1**:
Strangely, when I download models from HuggingFace, I get speeds around 200 mbps (22-25 Mbps downlaod). However, for any other download or when I am on bowser, I consistently get speeds of 17-18 mbps (2-3 Mbps downlaod)

**[Edit Sep 19]Few more details** :

How do I measure the WiFi speed?
I check the upload/download speed using a browser and see the update speed in the Ubuntu console. ALso used Google's default speed test utility from browser

I've also observed that when the computer uses WiFi, the remote desktop connection from my Windows laptop (Both are on the same network) is slow. But when connected with an Ethernet cable, it's smooth.

`nmcli d wifi list` screenshot, (i am using the second connection)
[image]

Comment: How are you testing your wifi speed?
It's best to differentiate between internet speed (AC1300 -> Access Point -> Internet) and your wifi speed (AC1300 -> Access Point). The Ubuntu drivers are only likly to influence your wifi speed, so that's where you should focus first. Try something like `nmcli d wifi list`.

Comment: In addition Jaydin's answer re testing your WiFi speed vs internet speed, also wondering if Windows and `23.04` are running on the same machine in the same location -- differences in either of those also introduce performance variables. 

And thank you, @Jaydin for suggesting `nmcli` -- that's new to me, and handy.

Comment: @Jaydin I check the upload/download speed using a browser and see the update speed in the Ubuntu console. ALso used Google's default speed test utility from browser,attached the output of nmcli command in my question.

Comment: @smcnally this desktop came with Windows, where everything worked fine. Now, it only has Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: As per the answer from @seeker your Archer T3U Plus likely uses the Realtek RTL8812BU chip. If you want, you can try to manually install the driver for it - here is [a related question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1256329/553502). I have similar TP link and had to manually compile and install the driver for mine to work properly. Unfortunately, I don't have your exact model so I cannot test your fix.

Comment: @Jaydin which version of linux  are you using ?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit the question to include results from the wireless script

Comment: @seeker I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 with linux 6.2.0-33-generic.

Answer (score 0):

I have the **TP-LINK T3U AC1300 USB Adapter** and am using the stock driver that comes with **22.04**. `lsusb` reports this as

> TP-Link Archer T3U [Realtek RTL8812BU]

I was connecting with slow speeds and often via 2.4 GHz until I deleted and re-connected to my access point:

`Settings` ... `WiFi` ... [*my access point SSID*] ... **Forget Connection**

I've been connecting to 5 GHz @ 270 Mbits/s since.

Comment: I'm also using the same USB Adapter and using the stock driver that comes with 23.04 . When I run lsusb, I see the following devices:
`TP-Link TP-Link UB500 Adapter`
`TP-Link 802.11ac NIC`
My WiFi is always connected to the 5GHz band, but strangely, I get slightly better speeds on the 2.4GHz band. The same device works perfectly on Windows.

Comment: I don't have more answers beyond troubleshooting suggestions: Per the screenshot added to your question, looks like one of those adapter's signals is stronger than the other. Can you disable the `802.11ac NIC` and see if that impacts your throughput with the `UB500`?

Comment: I have checked, the UB500 is the blue tooth dongle.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using at least WPA2.
wpa can not use the extended bandwidth due to the way it is encrypted.

wpa_supplicant.conf should read something like below.

```
network={
    ssid="example wpa2-eap network"
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    proto=WPA2
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP
    eap=TLS
    ca_cert="/etc/cert/ca.pem"
    private_key="/etc/cert/user.p12"
    private_key_passwd="PKCS#12 passhrase"
```

}